# Add Class to body if #hash is in the url

Tags: jquery, hash, modal-dialog

I have the following code, which adds a class to the body if there is #hash in the url - but it only works if I reload the browser.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        if (window.location.href.indexOf('#login') != -1) {
            $(document.body).addClass('modalOpen');
        }

    });
</script>
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong? I want it to add the class when someone arrives at homepage.com#login

Thanks in advance!
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code runs when the `document` is being loaded and if the user arrives at #login, the `document` will not be loaded again. The solution is to define your `function` separately

```
function hashChange() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('#login') != -1) {
        $(document.body).addClass('modalOpen');
    }
}
```

and call it at the `onhashchange` event:

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
    hashChange();
};
```

You can also call it when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `$('body').addClass('modalOpen');` without using `$(document.body).addClass('modalOpen');` as `body` is a tag and not a class as defined in  `.body`.

**CHANGED CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if (window.location.href.indexOf('#login') != -1) {
        $('body').addClass('modalOpen');
    }

});
```

Comment: Actually document.body gives you the body tag. Try it out in your browser console. The problem is that the hash changes after the document has been loaded.